# String templating

Tags: algorithm, template-engine

I have the task of designing a feature that generates Id numbers that follow rules that can be extended later.

For example; A system may require their id numbers be generated as follows: `18122424`. This would be broken down into: `[DepartmentId][YearCreated][Sequential]`. Department = 18, Year = 12, Sequence = 2424.

How do I go about designing a rule engine that allows the user to change it? I came up with a format like:

1. Dept(#)
2. Year(#)
3. Seq(#)
4. Initials(#) <-- Name initials.

So the rule for that Id above is: `[Dept(2)][Year(2)][Seq(4)]`. If I get this as a string, how do I parse it to get the rules? Regex or normal string search?

Is there an easier or more efficient way of doing this conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right, your question is about parsing the rule string, i.e. retrieving the field names and lenghts.

I would work one field at a time and possibly use a Regexpr for [ letters ( digits ) ], like

```
\[{[A-Za-z]+}\({[0-9]+}\)\]
```

(MSVC syntax, retrieve the two tagged expressions).

You'll also need to store a dictionary of possible field names and convert the digits to an integer.

Alternatively, combined C strchr and scanf can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "rule engine", this is just templating.

Whatever language you are using has some kind of templating, and a way to specify all of these formats. Just use that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who upvoted it.

*Generating the number*
 - you first have to decide the template. something like `depid-year-seq`. Assuming you have only these 3 "Variables". Then you should have have these variables mapped to original value. use a string parser and split the "given" template on `-`. It will give you array with index 0 = depid, 1 = year, 2 = seq. Loop through the array and create a string by using the corresponding values for each string on given index i.e. 
 - `0 = depid = "18"`
 - `1 = year = "18" + "12" = "1812"`
 - `2 = seq = "1812" + "1212" = "18121212"`

*Reverse*
you should parse your given number by splillting it up in 2-2-rest .. .. i guess you can pick up from here.